# Selenium: getting HTML of scrolled page

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to Selenium and I am trying to scroll to the bottom of Twitter profiles, so I can load all tweets for web scraping. I need to get the HTML of the already scrolled page, I tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
browser.get('https://twitter.com/earthpix/media')  # This page is just an example.
scroll = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
scroll.send_keys(Keys.END)
html = scroll.page_source

print (html)
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/k/Desktop/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    html = scroll.page_source
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'page_source'
```

Also, `browser.page_source` will not work for me, since it will only give me the not scrolled yet page.

Comment: See my answer using `innerHTML`... Let me know if you need more explanation...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get `page_source` of a `WebElement` hence the error:

> AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'page_source'

What you should be using is `get_attribute` with `innerHTML` in your case:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
browser.get('https://twitter.com/earthpix/media')  # This page is just an example.
scroll = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
scroll.send_keys(Keys.END)
html = scroll.get_attribute('innerHTML')

print (html)
```

Hope this helps you!